# Can't create new tab in Query Console (in MarkLogic)

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm just learning to use MarkLogic, going thru the tutorials, etc.  I'm getting an error message I don't understand. When I'm in the Query Console and need to create a new tab, I click the plus sign at the right end of the row of existing tabs, and I get the following error message instead of a new tab:

```
XDMP-COMPARE: (err:XPTY0004) qconsole:focus eq fn:true() -- Items not comparable: xs:untypedAtomic("") eq fn:true()
```

This recently worked, but now it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Brent, can you tell me which tutorial workspace you were using when you observed this problem?

Comment: In the "XQuery Use Cases" tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Open the exported workspace XML in your IDE and look through each "query" node.  The file should only have a single node with the attribute focus="true", the rest should be focus="false".  If you see more than one "true" or empty values "" (from your comment below), then change these all to "false", except for the one set to "true", and resave the file.  Then re-import the workspace back into Query Console.  This will fix the problem.

--

I've also filed a bug against Query Console since the application should be able to handle any malformed data gracefully.

Comment: Thank you.   I exported the XQuery Use Cases workspace.  In the resulting file, I found only one focus="true", but I did find 70 cases of focus="".  I replaced all of these with focus="false", re-imported the workspace, and the problem was solved.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.  Thanks for the detailed information.  I'll be sure to update the bug.

Comment: I've also updated the answer to be more general so it will cover all cases of malformed "focus" values.

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue occurred in my QConsole. MarkLogic Query console is not responding. Neither can open existing nor new query tabs. Cannot run queries. I thought it is browser specific and tried in all different browsers, the issue appeared to be the same. In the developer tools of the browser I have tried disabling the cache but no change in the issue.
I have also tried restarting the ML cluster, did not work that option either.

Here are few more observations:

1. Other users on the same ML, have no problem with the QConsole.
2. I tried in a different laptop connecting to same Qconsole, the issue still persists.
3. Looks like it all stated when I deleted one query tab with in a workspace.

From all the above observations, it draws my attention to the current workspace XML. @Brent Nelson's answer to this issue helped me isolate the problem.

solution that worked for me:
I have exported the workspace and observed that all of the queries within the workspace has the element "focus='false'". Changed one of the queries value to 'true', renamed the workspace xml and imported it into Qconsole.  This method worked for me.

The old workspace is still a problem. I cannot delete it or enter into it as it throws me back into the same situation.